# .NET Repeater - custom server validation

Tags: .net, validation

I do not understand how to make proper custom server side validation in repeater.

I have repeater control with three columns:
1) Register - checkbox 
2) Attended - checkbox
3) Time - textbox

I need to write server side custom validation that validates Time textbox value.

For now I have written the following custom validation in my repeater:

```
 <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptResidents" OnItemDataBound="rptResidents_ItemDataBound">
 ....
    <asp:CheckBox runat="server" CssClass="RegisterSpan" name="RegisterChkName" ID="chkRegister" />
    <asp:CheckBox runat="server" CssClass="AttendedSpan" name="AttendedChkName" ID="chkAttended" />
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtTime" Width="30px" MaxLength="3" Columns="3"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:CustomValidator runat="server" Width="1px" ID="valTimeRange" ControlToValidate="txtTime" OnServerValidate="valTimeRange_ServerValidate" Text="*" ErrorMessage="Minutes cannot exceed the minutes of the event" />
  ....
```

Server side validation function:

```
protected void valTimeRange_ServerValidate(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
{
    int maxAllowedMinutes = 0;
    maxAllowedMinutes = Convert.ToInt32(this.txtMaxAllowedMinutes.Text);

            int val = Convert.ToInt32(e.Value);
            if (val > maxAllowedMinutes)
            {
                e.IsValid = false;
            }
            else
            {
                e.IsValid = true;
            }           
}
```

This works fine. But I need to add additional logic. I need also to use checkboxes - Register and Attended  in my custom server side validation.

So ServerValidate function would look like:

```
protected void valTimeRange_ServerValidate(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
{
    if (CHECKBOX_REGISTER_IS_CHECKED && CHECKBOX_ATTENDED_IS_CHECKED) //?????
    {
            DO_VALIDATION_DESCRIBED_ABOVE
    }
    else
    {
        e.IsValid = true; //NO NEED TO VALIDATE TIME HERE OR ANY OTHER LOGIC COULD BE HERE
    }
}
```

So the problem here is - I do not understnd how to get checkbox values in server side validation method (both checkboxes come from repeater).

Comment: i think i found a good answer for your problem : http://stackoverflow.com/a/14654349/2914856

I see you are getting the maxAllowedMinutes from a textfield. Maybe it would be nice to use javascript or jQuery to validate these controls and validate client side. Unless you have a reason not to
use javascripts.

Answer (score 0):

**View the source and you will find:**

```
<input name="myRepeater$ctl00$myTextBox" type="text" id="myRepeater_myTextBox_0" />
<input name="myRepeater$ctl01$myTextBox" type="text" id="myRepeater_myTextBox_1" />
<input name="myRepeater$ctl02$myTextBox" type="text" id="myRepeater_myTextBox_2" />
```

From the code behind, you can access this generated id via the ClientID property. You can also access individual controls by searching through your repeater's Items property:

```
TextBox textBox2 = myRepeater.Items[1].FindControl("myTextBox");
```

**Edit**: You can explicitly set the ClientID for a control. You have to set its ClientIDMode to Static and change the ID when it is databound:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myRepeater.ItemDataBound += new RepeaterItemEventHandler(myRepeater_ItemDataBound);
    myRepeater.DataSource = new int[3];
    myRepeater.DataBind();
}

void myRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    var textbox = e.Item.FindControl("myTextBox");
    textbox.ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.Static;
    textbox.ID = "myTextBox" + (e.Item.ItemIndex + 1);
}
```

**Gives this HTML**:

```
<input name="myRepeater$ctl01$myTextBox1" type="text" id="myTextBox1" />
<input name="myRepeater$ctl02$myTextBox2" type="text" id="myTextBox2" />
<input name="myRepeater$ctl02$myTextBox3" type="text" id="myTextBox3" />
```

Thanks.