# How can i get an element id inside a asp repeater with javascript. I am trying to get the ID of the RadioButtons

Tags: javascript, asp.net, repeater, asprepeater

I have a table and inside the table i have an asp repeater.

```
<table id="repeaterTable">
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
<tr>
<td>
<b>Not Feasible:</b>&nbsp;<asp:RadioButton ID="notfeasibleRadioBtn" runat="server"/>&nbsp;<b>Feasible:</b>&nbsp;<asp:RadioButton ID="feasibleRadioBtn" runat="server" />                           
</td>
</tr>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</table>
```

Comment: Your repeater outputs n rows all with the same radiobutton id's, which is not html valid. Use a unique id, for example by putting the index number after the id

Comment: Now i understand. since i am using a repeater, all the id's will be the same (can't have multiple ids). The other part is where i got lost. What do you mean by "putting the index number after the id"?  @devqon

Comment: You probably have control over what to put in as ID, for example the index of the current item: Container.ItemIndex. Checkout this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14654174/set-id-of-items-in-a-repeater